# hide detailsview when using master/detail method

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, detailsview, master-detail

I am using a GridView that populates DetailsViews (master/detail method).  When I click on Select in the GridView and display a DetailsView, that view remains displayed after I Select another row from the GridView and it displays another DetailsView.  My question is:  how can I display only one DetailsView at the sameone time???

So far I have:

```
protected void grdMonster_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //grdMonster is GridView and "BookTitle" is datafield and pnlBooks is panel around BookTitle  
    //DetailsView
    if (grdMonster.SelectedValue.ToString() != "BookTitle")
        pnlBooks.Visible = false;
    else
        pnlBooks.Visible = true;
}
```

It doesn't work!  The BookTitle DetailsView doesn't display!
    }

Comment: Did you check to see whether `grdMonster.SelectedValue` is ever really `"BookTitle"`?

Comment: Yes, the DetailsView for BookTitle displays using the DetailsView sql as: <SelectParameters><asp:ControlParameter ControlID="grdMonster"       Name="BookTitle" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" /></SelectParameters>

Comment: That's logic and rules, not testing. Set a break point on `pnlBooks.Visible = true` and see if it ever gets there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by accident.  "BookTitle" needed to be in the DataKeyNames along with the following code (I added this code for something else):

protected void grdMonster_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string BookTitle = grdMonster.DataKeys[grdMonster.SelectedIndex]["BookTitle"].ToString();
        sqlDV1.SelectParameters.Clear();
        sqlDV1.SelectParameters.Add("BookTitle", BookTitle);
        dtv1.DataBind();
}

Not quite sure how that works, but it does.